# Can I access javascripts from iframe parent on another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I control both domains and could set whatever policies necessary. The domain in the iframe uses pretty much the same libraries and I was hoping to leech them off the parent if possible.

**To be clear, I'm not asking how to make a cross-domain request. I'm asking how to get scripts from an iframe's parent, when the parent is on another domain.**

I'm getting a permission error with this (trying jQuery here but same with my other libraries):

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined") {
  var iframebody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var jQuery = function (selector) { return parent.jQuery(selector, iframebody); };
  var $ = jQuery;
}
$("<h1>Hello World</h1>").appendTo("body");
```

This would work if they were on the same domain.

I know this is cross-domain and is blocked for security reasons, but considering I control both domains and neither are security sensitive, I could set any policies as lax as I want to.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you include the js from the same source in both pages, it will be just loaded once, but will be accessible on both sites:

```
//parent/main.html
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<iframe src="http://other/iframe.html"></iframe>
<script>
  $(document.body).html("wohoo");
</script>

//other/iframe.html
 <script src="http://parent/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document.body).html("wohoo");
</script>
```

So if theyre accessed in the iframe, the script is just loaded once, and if you access each of them without the other, it will still work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postMessage to pass information back and forth between frames and their parent window.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

You'll have to run the code to modify the element in the domain where it lives, but you can set a post message handlerler in the parent to kick it off.

```
// child window (iframe content)
parent.postMessage("hi there", "https://parent.domain.here");


// parent window
window.addEventListener("message", function(message){
    $("<h1>"+message+"</h1>").appendTo("body");
});
```